# Change orientation of image using Ion in android

Tags: android, image, orientation

here i have a quick question on Orientation related.

I am developing an application which includes images.here i am displaying images getting from storage using cursors.

And i used [ION](https://github.com/koush/ion)  library for loading images in gridview. all are working fine but problem is while displaying images in gridview image orientation changes.(Ex : image orientation is portrait but thumbnail image displaying as landscape but original image displaying normally)

i tried and googled for solution but no result. please advise your suggestions how to overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question an hour ago and after looking at the examples I reached to this method using the Ion library.

```
Transform rotation90 = new Transform() {
  @Override
  public Bitmap transform(Bitmap b) {
      Bitmap rotated;
      BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
      Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

      matrix.postRotate(90);
      options.inSampleSize = 2;

      // Rotate bitmap 90 degrees
      rotated = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                                     b,
                                     0,
                                     0,
                          b.getWidth(),
                         b.getHeight(),
                                matrix,
                                  true
       );

       return rotated;
  }

  @Override
  public String key() {
     return null;
  }
};
```

As for usage:

```
    Ion.with(/*imageview*/).transform(rotation90).load(/*uri*/);
```